# React Redux Toolkit does not add object into a state array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, redux, state

I am redux beginner and I am using Redux Toolkit to create a reducer.

My initialState variable is:

```
const initialState = {
  value: [],
  status: 'idle',
};
```

Then I create a slice with this reducer in it:

```
reducers: {
    add: (state, action) => {
      state.value.push (0);    // This works (pushing a number)
      state.value.push ("");   // This works also (pushing a string)
      state.value.push ([]);   // This works also (pushing an array)
      state.value.push ({});   // This FAILS (pushing an object)
    },
}
```

The error message browser gives when trying to push an object into the state array:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I want to  indeed push an object into the state. What I am doing wrong? Does this has something to do with that, that you can't output an object variable as such inside expression? i.e.

```
const person = {name: "bill"};

<div>{person]</div> //error?
<div>{person.name}</div> //ok
```

Comment: All right the problem was solved. The object push indeed works. The problem was not a redux toolkit but a react problem. I had indeed <div>{state]</div> experssion in my react code, and that was that caused the problem, not redux toolkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. The object push indeed works. The problem was not a redux toolkit but a react problem. I had indeed {state] expression in my react code, and that was that caused the problem, not redux toolkit.

Code:

```
const cart = useSelector(selectCart);

<div>{cart]</div>
```

So no problem with the Toolkit.